Guy goes to insane asylum, escapes and ends up on the beach
I don't remember how it starts, but I remember this guy was having trouble with his wife.  For some reason he ends up in mental institute or asylum. Anyways, when he gets there, there is this fat guy (that stabs people) who stays in the cell with him. They end up escaping or getting out and at the end they are both on the beach. The fat guy tries stabbing the main dude in a comedic way. It is from the 80s or 90s. I think it's in color. The main dude kinda looks like main guy from One Flew Over the Cuckoos Nest (Jack Nicholson). The fat guy kinda looks the Crazy fat guy who shoots himself in Full Metal Jacket (Vincent D'Onofrio). I would really love some help, I've been looking for it FOREVER.
Additional info: The houses looked kinda like the houses in Vegas. I also remember when he was getting sent to the mental institute the main dude or owner I guess, he was in his office with him and he either shook his hand or hugged him and he died. If I remember right, the main character was fighting with his wife about their kid.

Hmm...not a lot to go on in terms of searching....anything else you can remember?

Yeah the houses looked kinda like the houses in Vegas google houses in vegas for a visual and I also remember when he was getting sent to mental institute the main dude or owner I guess He was in his offuce with and he either shook his hand or hugged him and he died  and If i remember right The main Character was fighting with his wife about their kid I also found a video with a picture from the movie on the thumbnail on youtube yesterday but I was in private browsing and forgot to go back and look at it before I exited

J.N. & V.D'O. have an Oracle of Bacon number of 2, so they were never in the same movie. https://oracleofbacon.org/movielinks.php?a=Jack+Nicholson+(I)&b=vincent+d%27onofrio&use_using=1&u0=on&use_genres=1&g0=on&g4=on&g8=on&g16=on&g20=on&g1=on&g5=on&g9=on&g13=on&g17=on&g21=on&g25=on&g2=on&g6=on&g10=on&g14=on&g22=on&g26=on&g3=on&g11=on&g15=on&g23=on&g27=on

I just said thats what they Kinda looked like, All from my mental images from the movie.

I think it's The End, (1978), with Burt Reynolds and Dom DeLuise:

California real-estate salesman Wendell "Sonny" Lawson (Burt Reynolds)
  is informed by his doctor (Norman Fell) that he's dying from a rare
  toxic blood disease and has six months to live. Not wanting to endure
  the inevitable pain, nor wanting to spend his last days in a hospital
  bed, he decides to take his own life.
...
After a failed suicide attempt with pills, Lawson ends up at a
  psychiatric hospital. There he befriends a disturbed fellow patient,
  Marlon Borunki (Dom DeLuise), who agrees to help in Sonny's quest to
  end it all.

The trailer is on Youtube.  At about 2:05 you can see his doctor at the psychiatric hospital, (Carl Reiner), die as they are shaking hands.  At 2:20 you can see Marlon try to stab Sonny comedically on the beach. 

YES OMG THANK YOU Best movie site ever you bet your ass ill be back if i need anymore help
